# The breakpoint will not currently be hit - debuging feature receiver

Tags: error, feature-activation, feature-receiver, debugging

I need to debug my feature receiver, so I set up few breakpoints, but when I hit F5 in VS2010, they are all missed, and it says that **"The breakpoint will not currently be hit. No symbols have been loaded for this document."** What should I do to be able to debug my feature receiver?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please follow this tutorial, I have done it thousands of time and it always work the same way.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798479.aspx

Comment: The key is setting the deployment configuration to No Activation otherwise your Feature Receiver runs during deployment and cannot be debugged

Comment: Using System.Diagnostic.Break() will work perfectly on activating, or am I wrong here ?

Answer (score 2):

Also the dlls are deployed in GAC , so make sure change the settings. Follow this article

http://www.sharepointnutsandbolts.com/2007/03/how-to-debug-sharepoint-feature.html

Answer (score 0):

First try rebuilding your project
If that doesn't work, try to clean the project.

If that also doesn't work follow these steps.

1. Right click your project
2. Select [Properties]
3. Select the [Build] tab
4. Make sure [Define DEBUG constant] and [Define TRACE constant] are
   checked
5. Click the [Advanced] button at the bottom of the Build tabpage
6. Make sure that [Debug Info] is set to [full]
7. Click [OK] and rebuild the project